# How to parse XML url in text

Tags: python, xml

In my xml example

```
<sample>
    <para>This text is sample paragraph with <url>https://www.google.com</url>. Thank you!</para>
</sample>
```

I would like to extract the following sentence from xml using python3.

```
This text is sample paragraph with https://www.google.com/. Thank you!
```

So I used Python 3 code as below.

```
# Sample.py
# root = xml root, xml = xml namespace
description = root.findall('./{0}sample/{0}para'.format(namespace))

for i in description:
    print(i.text)
```

But, Sample.py code above was very different from the output I wanted.

```
# Sample.py Output
This text is sample paragraph with
```

How can I print the text that includes the value in the url tag I want?
(*It excludes simply using findall() func and attaching url(i.e., the location of url tags is unknown).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup` this works

```py
soup.find("para").text
>>> 'This text is sample paragraph with https://www.google.com. Thank you!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Below (no need to use an external library)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml1 = '''<sample>
    <para>This text is sample paragraph with <url>https://www.google.com</url>. Thank you!</para>
</sample>'''

root1 = ET.fromstring(xml1)
para = root1.find('.//para')
print('{} {} {}'.format(para.text, list(para)[0].text, list(para)[0].tail))
```

output

```
This text is sample paragraph with  https://www.google.com . Thank you!
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well. However, this method requires an exception if there are more than one url tag in the middle or not using url tag. So I just decided to use bs4 like the above method.Thanks again for your time and consideration.